# Pseudocode check. Needs validation for assignment

Tags: vb.net, pseudocode

I have already turned this in so you won't be helping me cheat. Just wondering if this looks right:

The assignment:
Input a list of employee names and salaries, and determine the
mean (average) salary as well as the number of salaries above and
below the mean.

The Plan:
Allow input of names and salaries
Calculate Mean
Sort values
Count values above Mean
Count values below Mean

```
//This program will allow a user to input an employee name and salary
//The output will contain the mean salary 
//as well as the number of salaries above and below the mean
//
//Arrays Used:
//Name(K) = Array for employee names
//Salary(K) = Array for salaries
//
//Variables Used:
//Mean = Mean of all employees Salaries
//UpMean = Number of Employees making more than the mean
//DwnMean = Number of Employees making less than the mean
//Sum = Sum of all salaries
//CountM = Counter for Mean
//CountUp = Counter for # of salaries above mean
//CountDwn = Counter for # of salaries below mean

Main
    Call WelcomeMessage
    Call InputData
    Call Calculate
    Call OutputData
End Program

WelcomeMessage
    Write, “Beginning the Salary Program” 
End WelcomeMessage

InputData
    Declare Name(100) Of Strings
    Declare Salary(100) Of Real
    Declare Mean, UpMean, DwnMean As Real
    Set Sum = 0
    Set CountM = 0
    Set CountUp = 0
    Set CountDwn = 0
    Write, "Enter Employee name and Salary."
    Write, "Enter *,0 when done."
    Input Name(K), Salary(K)
    While Name(K) <> "*"
        Set CountM = CountM + 1
        Set Sum = Sum + Salary
        Write, "Enter Employee name and Salary."
        Write, "Enter *,0 when done."
        Input Name(K), Salary(K)
    End While
End InputData

Calculation
    //Here Mean is found
    Set Mean = Sum / CountM
    //Here Number of Employees making more than the mean is found
    For K = Step 1 to CountM
        If Salary(K) > Mean Then
            Set CountUp = CountUp + 1
        End If
    //Here Number of Employees making more than the mean is found
    Set CountDwn = CountM - CountUp
    //The above algorythm doesn't account for the possibility 
    //of someone making exactly the average so subtract 1 to reconcile
    If Salary(K) = Mean Then
            Set CountDwn = CountDwn - 1
    End If
End Calculation

OutputData
    Write, "There were,"  CountM, "salaries entered."
    Write, "The mean salary is:", Mean
    Write, "There are", CountUp, "employees who make more than the average"
    Write, "There are", CountDwn, "employees who make less than the average"
End OutputData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note about calculating `CountDwn`:

Your "subtract 1 to reconcile" will, depending on how exactly the `For` loop works in the implementation language, (a) generate an "undeclared variable"-type error, (b) generate an "index out of range" error, or (c) subtract one IFF the *last* salary was exactly equal to the average.  (Also, your code doesn't include an `End For` in `Calculation`, but I assume it should be immediately after the first `End If` in that function.)

Instead of calculating `CountDwn` from `CountUp` (after all, every single salary *could* be equal to the average), I'd suggest including it in the loop:

```
Calculation
    //Here Mean is found
    Set Mean = Sum / CountM

    For K = Step 1 to CountM
        //Here Number of Employees making more than the mean is found
        If Salary(K) > Mean Then
            Set CountUp = CountUp + 1
        End If

        //Here Number of Employees making less than the mean is found
        If Salary(K) < Mean Then
            Set CountDwn = CountDwn + 1
        End If
    End For
End Calculation
```

Note that `CountUp + CountDwn` is not necessarily equal to `CountM`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks ok. The only thing I have to suggest, is to use a do-while structure while reading input to name/salery. As you can see you have the same logic before the loop begins, and in the loop:

```
Write, "Enter Employee name and Salary."
Write, "Enter *,0 when done."
Input Name(K), Salary(K)
```

Also, the pseudo code will not compile, since you are calling Calculate but the routine is called Calculation ;)

> Thanks for the suggestions. Not really
>   familiar yet with Do-While. What would
>   that look like? I though maybe
>   something about the input should
>   change in the loop but wasn't sure
>   how.

It could look something like this:

```
Do 
    Write, "Enter Employee name and Salary."
    Write, "Enter *,0 when done."
    Input Name(K), Salary(K)
    If Name(K) <> "*"
        Set CountM = CountM + 1
        Set Sum = Sum + Salary
    Else
        BreakLoop
    End If
End While (true)
```

It's not really a big difference, but more a matter of taste really. Personally I think it's easier to read, since the code is written in such a way that you easily realize that you are supposed to input something, check input and do something depending on the input.

In your while loop the Set CountM etc come after (in the text flow) the first input, but before the rest of the input, which means you have to look back into the top of the loop to understand that it does something after the previous "round" in the loop. Now this is just a small loop, but if it was 30 rows long (god forbid) you'd have to scroll up to see what's going on. If you know what I mean :)

Comment: I don't really think giving instructions like do ... while (true), with a break statement in the code, is good style to teach a new person. Code should be self documenting, and the execution flow here is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
FINAL ALGORITHM

START
OUTPUT "Enter the number of parcels"
INPUT NUMBEROFPARCELS
INTEGER PRICE = 0
INTEGER PARCELWEIGHT [1:NUMBEROFPARCELS]
INTEGER TOTALPRICE = 0

FOR PARCELLOOP = 1 TO NUMBEROFPARCELS
    INTEGER REJECT = 0
    INTEGER ACCEPT = 0
    INTEGER ACCEPTWEIGHT = 0
    INTEGER REJECTEDPARCELS = 0

    OUTPUT "Enter the weight of the parcel in kg"
    INPUT WEIGHT
    IF (WEIGHT < 1) THEN
        REJECT = REJECT + 1
        OUTPUT "The weight of the parcel should be atleast 1kg"
    ELSE
        IF (WEIGHT > 10) THEN
            REJECT = REJECT + 1
            OUTPUT "The weight of the parcel should be less than 10kg"
    ENDIF
    IF (WEIGHT > 1) THEN
        IF (WEIGHT < 10) THEN
            PARCELWEIGHT[PARCELLOOP] = WEIGHT
        ENDIF
    ENDIF


    OUTPUT "Enter the first dimension of the parcel in cm"
    INPUT DIMENSION1
    IF (DIMENSION1 > 80 ) THEN
        REJECT = REJECT + 1
        OUTPUT "Each dimension of the parcel should be less than 80"
    ENDIF

    OUTPUT "Enter the second dimension of the parcel in cm"
    INPUT DIMENSION2
    IF (DIMENSION2 > 80 ) THEN
        REJECT = REJECT + 1
        OUTPUT "Each dimension of the parcel should be less than 80"
    ENDIF

    OUTPUT "Enter the third dimension of the parcel in cm"
    INPUT DIMENSION3
    IF (DIMENSION3 > 80 ) THEN
        REJECT = REJECT + 1
        OUTPUT "Each dimension of the parcel should be less than 80"
    ENDIF

    TOTALDIMENSION = DIMENSION1 + DIMENSION2 + DIMENSION3
    IF (TOTALDIMENSION > 200 ) THEN
        REJECT = REJECT + 1
        OUTPUT "The size of the parcel should be less than 200cm"
    ENDIF

    IF (REJECT > 0 ) THEN
        OUTPUT "Your parcel has been rejected for the reasons above"
        REJECTEDPARCELS = REJECTEDPARCELS + 1
    ENDIF

    IF (REJECT = 0)THEN
        OUTPUT "Your parcel has been accepted"
        ACCEPT = ACCEPT + 1 
        ACCEPTWEIGHT = ACCEPTWEIGHT + WEIGHT
    END IF

    INTEGER PARCELSACCEPTED = ACCEPT
    INTEGER TOTALWEIGHT = ACCEPTWEIGHT
    INTEGER PARCELSREJECTED = REJECTEDPARCELS

    OUTPUT "The number of parcels accepted is " PARCELSACCEPTED " and the total weight of the parcels is " TOTALWEIGHT
    OUTPUT "The number of parcels rejected is " PARCELSREJECTED
NEXT PARCELLOOP

FOR PRICELOOP = 1 TO NUMBEROFPARCELS
    IF (PARCELWEIGHT[PARCELLOOP] < 5) THEN
        PRICE = PRICE + 10
        TOTALPRICE = TOTALPRICE +PRICE
    END IF

    IF (PARCELWEIGHT[PARCELLOOP] > 5) THEN
        PRICE = ((PARCELWEIGHT[PARCELLOOP] - 5)*0.10)/100
        TOTALPRICE = TOTALPRICE +PRICE
    END IF

    OUTPUT "The price of the parcel is " PRICE
NEXT PRICELOOP

OUTPUT "The total price of all the parcels is " TOTALPRICE
STOP
```